# DLL references DLL

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a .NET DLL (DLLA), which is referenced by app1 (copy local).  Therefore when I build app1, DLLA is placed in the BIN folder of app1.  DLLA references DLLB, which is hardly ever used.

I use to notice that DLLB was placed in the BIN folder of app1, but this does not happen anymore.  Is there a reason for this that I do not understand? How does app1 decide whether or not to put DLLB into its BIN folder?

Comment: Is DLLB available? It won't be picked up if it can't be "found" under more strict conditions than those for DLLA. (Well technically just different). The easiest solution to this problem is to reference DLLB, is that an option in this case?

Answer (score 4):

When you compile your application, the compiler looks for references and usage of your references. If you are not using any class, static method, or anything else from a reference, it is not needed, therefore it will not be included. For example, if you have Project A, B and C. If C references A and A references B, you will not get a `B.dll` unless you use B at all:

```
using B;
namespace A
{
    public class Class1
    {

    }
}
```

The previous code will not include a dll in your bin folder. However, the following will:

```
using B;
namespace A
{
    public class Class1
    {
        void c()
        {
            B.Class1 b = new B.Class1();
            Console.Write(b.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks +1.  If A.DLL references B.DLL and B.dll references C.DLL then does A.dll have to reference C.DLL?  I have read some questions on here from people who get errors if this reference is not in place.

Comment: If A doesn't use C at all I don't think it needs a reference at all (I just tested with small projects and it allowed me). There might be more complex circumtances (maybe through Reflection) in which probably you could load a dll in runtime. In which case you would still need a path to the dll (and B might force the dll generation automatically).

Comment: Are you able to provide a Reflection example where there could be a problem?

Comment: I can't think of any scenario. That's why I said "There might be", maybe in a more complex scenario like that it _could_ happen. It's never happened to me though.